# Why the pycurl response is different on my nginx server compared to the response on my computer

Tags: python, request, instagram, pycurl

I use python pycurl for get this page https://www.instagram.com/nilliewinnie/?__a=1.

On my computer pycurl return json object (that I want) but on my nginx server they return a page with javascript and html (page with grey instagram logo on center of the page)

It's the same code on my computer and on my server :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pycurl
import certifi
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO()

crl = pycurl.Curl()
crl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
crl.setopt(crl.URL, 'https://www.instagram.com/nilliewinnie/?__a=1')
crl.setopt(crl.WRITEDATA, buffer)
crl.perform()
crl.close()

print(buffer.getvalue())
```

Where can it come from? I tried with `resquets.get()` and it's the same problem

Thanks for your help

Comment: Instagram tries to prevent scraping when it knows the request is definitely not coming from legit client or user ..

Comment: many portals block requests if they think it can't be real user. They can have IP of your server on blacklist and then you have to use some proxy server - but portals can have also proxy servers on blacklist.